# Why java type erasure is needed at runtime at all?

Tags: java, jvm, type-erasure, type-systems

Below is an excerpt from [java documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html)

> Because of type erasure, `List<Number>` and `List<String>` both become List. Consequently, the compiler allows the assignment of the object l, which has a raw type of List, to the object ls.

Also from the same documentation

> Consider the following example:

```
List l = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<String> ls = l;       // unchecked warning
l.add(0, new Integer(42)); // another unchecked warning
String s = ls.get(0);      // ClassCastException is thrown
```

> During type erasure, the types ArrayList and List become ArrayList and List, respectively.

Why compiler can't show this as an error (instead of warning). Could someone kindly help with an example where warning is needed and will cause an issue (or make certain useful patterns impossible) when warning becomes an error.

Comment: Raw types are _potentially_ unsafe, not _necessarily_ unsafe. Their use can be legit and justified. The warning just means that the code cannot be proven type safe by the compiler.

Comment: As for why erasure is needed at all, [here](https://openjdk.org/projects/valhalla/design-notes/in-defense-of-erasure) is an explanation by one of the language architects

Comment: “*Why compiler can't show this as an error (instead of warning)*” is an entirely different question than “*Why java type erasure is needed **at runtime** at all?*”

Answer (score 2):

Java gained type variables in java 1.5. Before java 1.5, they **did not exist**.

Java also strongly dislikes releasing new versions such that 'upgrading' is more involved than just 'simply compile your existing code with the new compiler and it all just works exactly like it did before'. Also, 'you can run code compiled with the `javac` from java 1.4, on the `java.exe` from 1.5 and it runs fine'.

Why? Well, because otherwise you get a split community, and because most projects use 500 dependencies, that is hugely detrimental. You can't 'upgrade' from java 1.4 to 1.5 until each and every single last one of those 500 deps has upgraded.

Combine these 2 facts and generics makes sense:

- Why erasure at all? Because how else could it work? Class files stemming from javac1.4 cannot possibly have the generics info, given that they did not exist when javac1.4 was released!
- Why 'raw types'? Because pre-generics code by their nature have them (`List<T>` would be a compiler error on java 1.4), and by their nature, there *is no* sanity, typevar-wise. You could write this:

```
List foo = new ArrayList();
foo.add(5);
foo.add("hello");
```

and it compiles just fine on javac 1.4. **Therefore it MUST also compile on javac 1.5**. As a compromise, if you attempt to compile that on javac from 1.5, it works and produces a class file that acts identically, but you *do* get warnings.

java 1.5 is now 25 years old or whatnot. So it all seems weird and archaic now. But you're asking 'why'. This is why.